# Why is MySQL receiving such a large serialized object?

Tags: multisite, options

I have gotten a 20GB error log that has an entry of repetitive serialized objects that look like this:

```
a:2:{s:8:\"schedule\";b:0;s:4:\"args\";a:0:{}}}i:1440184624;a:1:{s:32:\"40cd750bba9870f18aada2478b24840a\"
```

Does anyone know what is causing this, and how I can either minimize how large it gets or disable it?

I am using multisite, and this entry is being updated in one of our site's wp_?_options table.